# Does [hipchat] remain appropriate?

Tags: discussion, tags

[The chat wars are heating up as $8 billion Atlassian totally reinvents its app to take on Microsoft and Slack](http://uk.businessinsider.com/atlassian-launches-hipchat-successor-stride-2017-9?r=US&IR=T).

[On September 7, 2017, Atlassian discontinued the cloud-based HipChat, replacing it with HipChat's successor, called Stride, which offers additional features to enhance efficiency of collaboration. The client-hosted HipChat Data Center continues to be supported.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HipChat)

Is [HipChat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/hipchat/info) currently on topic here (rather than, perhaps, [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)) and,

If **Yes**, should [hipchat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hipchat) be renamed [stride](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stride)?

If **No**, should these Qs be Closed?:

[How does one message a hyperlink with custom text in HipChat?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/48469/how-does-one-message-a-hyperlink-with-custom-text-in-hipchat)
[Copy-paste from PowerPoint to HipChat results in PNG, not text](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79946/copy-paste-from-powerpoint-to-hipchat-results-in-png-not-text)
[Public web chat room on HipChat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60625/public-web-chat-room-on-hipchat)
[How to check who's an admin of the room?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/97462/how-to-check-whos-an-admin-of-the-room)
[Images in HipChat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/98335/images-in-hipchat) 
[Disable HipChat notifications per room](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45661/disable-hipchat-notifications-per-room)
[How to manage multiple teams in HipChat?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/94616/how-to-manage-multiple-teams-in-hipchat)
[How do I make the HipChat emoticon bigger?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/104441/how-do-i-make-the-hipchat-emoticon-bigger)

or perhaps the tag [hipchat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hipchat) renamed [hipchat-data-center](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hipchat-data-center) ?

... Or "other"?

Comment: Stride is still not in full release.  Please don't close these questions as of yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stride is just hitting public beta in the next few weeks.  I'd say that the [hipchat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hipchat) should stick around until they completely phase out the "HipChat Cloud" version (which can be found by clicking on the link at the top of the stride.com page).